# Xcode: Changing my UIBarButton item title if pressed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying to set my UIBarbutton items title dependant on whether the buttons been clicked or not, I think I am very close however not sure why it isn't working. I am using a storyboard and the barbuttons name/method is "share1" and all I have is it is connected to it on the storyboard, and heres my code so far:

in my .h:

```
- (IBAction)share1:(id)sender;
```

and in my .m:

```
#import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController2 ()


@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL sharepressed;


@end

@implementation ViewController2

- (IBAction)share1:(id)sender {

    //i am trying to open a menu in this but that shouldn't affect the button.

    if (self.sideMenu.isOpen) {
        self.sharepressed = YES;
        [self.sideMenu close];
    }

    else {
        [self.sideMenu open];

    }

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Share" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(share1:)];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (_sharepressed) {
        self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem  = [[UIBarButtonItem    alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hide" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(share1:)];
    _sharepressed |= _sharepressed;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all. You may want to use `self.sharepressed` instead of `_sharepressed`. Only use the second way inside initializer, setter, and getter methods. And I suggest you use capital letters to denote when a new word in you variable name begins. For example, instead of `sharepressed` use `sharePressed`, this makes it easier to read specially when the name is really long.

Now about your code. You don't want to allocate `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem` again when the action occurs. What you may want to do is just to change the title. Better use something like this:

- If you are using a navigation controller

  ```
  self.title = @"Share";
  ```
- If you are using a navigation bar

  ```
  self.navigationBar.title = @"Share"; // navigationBar is the name you gave to the object
  ```